# Django Image Upload

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to upload an image using a form with Django. First off, I don't know if I should be doing this with django or a combination of jQuery and Django. Second, I am looking for a simple tutorial using 1.7 and can't seem to find one. Is there something like [this](https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield) for version 1.7. I'm just looking for something super simple and then I can expand from there.

Answer (score 0):

Code from your link should work perfectly in django 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

The linked tutorial will work for Django 1.7, along with pretty much any tutorial. The one thing you're going to run into that's different in 1.7 is that the migrations are built into Django now instead of using a 3rd Party App called South.

You **definitely** should be using django forms to upload the image, it's really simple once you get the hang of it - it's just like another field. You definitely should **not** use a combination of JQuery and Django.

If Django can't do what you're wanting to accomplish, take a look at [Django Crispy Forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I would suggest getting an understanding of just using Django image uploading first through, regardless.

Hope this helps. Also take a look at the [Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/) of file uploads, if you haven't already.